# Pass text features along with image data to a CNN model

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am trying to approach a multi label image classification problem,for which i have image data but i also have some other features like gender etc, but the issue is that i will get this information during testing, in other words during testing only the image information will be provided.

My question is how can i use these extra features to help my image model which is a convolution Neural Network even though i wont have this info during testing?

Any advice will be helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This is a really open ended question. I can give you some general guidelines on how this can work.

`keras` model API supports multiple inputs as well as [`merge`](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) layers. For example you can have something like this:

```
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model

image = Input(...)
text = Input(...)

... # apply layers onto image and text

from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
combined = Concatenate()([image, text])

... # apply layers onto combined

model = Model([image, text], [combined])
```

This way you can have a `model` that takes multiple inputs that can make use of all of your data sources. `keras` has tools to combine your different inputs to produce one output. The part where this becomes open ended is the architecture.

Right now you should probably pass `image` through a `CNN`, and then `merge` the output with `text`. You have to tweak the exact specifications, such as how you handle each input, your `merge` method, and how you handle the combined output.

A good example of `merge` being used is [here](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/cgan/cgan.py), where a GAN is given latent noise in the form of an image but also a label to determine what kind of image it should generate. Both the `discriminator` and the `generator` make use of the `multiply` merge layer to combine their inputs.

Comment: Joint image/text classifier in Keras
https://gist.github.com/alexminnaar/a286912efa417dfd0f25bd33992c3d6b